Change font color of form button without selection
I would like to remove selection from code because that usually means it is more efficient and robust.
So there is a code that works fine but selection cannot be removed in the way I expected.
This code changes the color of a form button:
thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").shapes.Range.(Array("Button 3")).Select
With Selection.Font
 .color = 10
End with

But the selection cannot be removed this way:
thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").shapes.Range.(Array("Button 3")).Font.color = 10

It drops runtime error: 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.
How can we remove selection?
Update and Solution:
thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").shapes.Range.("Button 3").TextFrame.Characters.Font.color = 10

So Array() is dropped from ShapeRange, and TextFrame.Characters. is added to the reference.

Not sure, but maybe something like thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").shapes.Range.(Array("Button 3")).TextRange.Font.color = 10 or thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").shapes.Range.(Array("Button 3")).TextRange.Characters.Font.color = 10?

@cybernetic.nomad No, all these drop unsupported property error:
.Range.(Array("Button 3")).TextRange.Font.color = 10
.Range.(Array("Button 3")).TextRange.Characters.Font.color = 10
.Range.(Array("Button 3")).Characters.Font.color = 10

thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").shapes.Range.("Button 3").TextFrame.Characters.Font.color = 10

So Array() is dropped from ShapeRange, and TextFrame.Characters. is added to the reference.
